# Is there a native way to make a url with params in Typescript like $.param(params)

Tags: javascript, typescript

I need to create a dynamic URL with typescript, in javascript I had the next code:

```
        var params = {
            param1: 'token',
            param2: 'anyvalue'
        };

        return 'https://any.com/?' + $.param(params);
```

Is there any way to do it natively with Typescript?

Comment: if you write a function to do it....

Comment: `URL_BASE + '/?' + Object.entries(params).map(p=> p.join('=')).join('&')`